# MS SQL select where binary field via PHP

Tags: php, sql-server

In sql server 2016 I have some tables.
One of them is:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[_Reference31](
[_IDRRef] [binary](16) NOT NULL,
[_Code] [nchar](9) NOT NULL,
[_Fld527RRef] [binary](16) NULL)
```

And the other one is like:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[_Document8755](
    [_IDRRef] [binary](16) NOT NULL,
    [_Number] [nchar](9) NOT NULL,
    [_Fld8997RRef] [binary](16) NOT NULL,
    [_Fld8999] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [_Fld9000] [datetime] NOT NULL)
```

PHP code is like this:

```
$data=array();
$STH = $DBHMS->prepare("SELECT _Fld534, _IDRRef AS id, _Code FROM _Reference31");
$STH->execute();
$STH->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
while($row=$STH->fetch()){
    $STH2 = $DBHMS->prepare("SELECT _IDRRef, _Number, _Fld8999, _FLd9000 FROM _Document8755 WHERE _Fld8997RRef=:id");
    $STH2->bindParam(':id',  $row['id'], PDO::PARAM_LOB, 0, PDO::SQLSRV_ENCODING_BINARY);
    $STH2->execute();
    $STH2->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    $row['total_agreements']=$STH2->rowCount();
        while($row2=$STH2->fetch()){
            array_push($row['agreements'],$row2);
        }
        array_push($data,$row);
}
echo(json_encode($data));
```

The problem is that total_agreements is always zero, but when I'm running the second query manually in Management Studio it works.

Comment: Screen the table sin phpmyadmin please. Can you explain why binary field and for what usage?

Answer (score 0):

```
$STH2->bindParam(':id', hex2bin($row['id']), PDO::PARAM_LOB, 0, PDO::SQLSRV_ENCODING_BINARY);
```

works

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.